# Schema and xml, elements with same name diffrent types,

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

So im building a large Schema file that takes alot of smaller schema files, and i was wondering if it is posibel to have a element with the same name getting diffrent types, and if it can be achived with namespaces in any ways.

```
<ele2>
    <Test Name="Timetable" important="no">
        <Class>className.something</Class> 
    </Test>
    <Test Name="Database" important="yes">
        <Class>className.something</Class>
        <Database>jk</Database>
    </Test>
</ele2>
```

I would like to know if it is posibel to have several Test elements that gets diffrent types from the schema files

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"  
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:include schemaLocation="file:///C:\Users\Desktop\Timetable.xsd" />
<xs:include schemaLocation="file:///C:\Users\Desktop\Database.xsd" />

<xs:element name="ele1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ele2">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Test" type="TimetableType" />
                        <xs:element name="Test" type="DatabaseType" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the "Element Declarations Consistent" constraint (which is present in both XSD 1.0 and XSD 1.1) prevents you having two sibling elements with the same name and different types.

Of course if the elements are in different namespaces then they are not considered to "have the same name", so this constraint does not apply.